# F# Weird pattern matching result

Tags: f#

I'm writing a binary search implementation. The problem I have is with a pattern matching block.

This code using pattern matching returns weird results. The first match block does not return what I expect. It warns me that `(_,_)` is never reached.

```
let binSearch (item:double) (arr:list<double>) =
    let rec binSearchRec first last =
        if first > last then
            let lastIndex = arr.Length-1
            let len = arr.Length
            match (first, last) with
            | (0, -1) -> System.String.Format("ITEM SMALLER THAN {0}", arr.[0])
            | (len, lastIndex) -> System.String.Format("ITEM BIGGER THAN {0}", arr.[lastIndex])
            | (_,_) -> System.String.Format("IN BETWEEN {0} AND {1}", arr.[last], arr.[first])
        else
            let mid = (first+last)/2
            match item.CompareTo(arr.[mid]) with
            | -1 -> binSearchRec first (mid-1)
            | 0 -> "CONTAINS"
            | 1 -> binSearchRec (mid+1) last
    binSearchRec 0 (arr.Length-1)
```

Replacing that first `match (first, last)` call with this if-else alternative works well:

```
if first = 0 && last = -1 then
    System.String.Format("ITEM SMALLER THAN {0}", arr.[0])
else if first = len && last = lastIndex then
    System.String.Format("ITEM BIGGER THAN {0}", arr.[lastIndex])
else
    System.String.Format("IN BETWEEN {0} AND {1}", arr.[last], arr.[first])
```

I don't understand how that match call is different from this if-else call and why this works well but the pattern matching block does not.

A weird result is that printing len in the `(len, lastIndex)` match returns wrong numbers inside the match. For an array of length three a print of `len` before the match statement will show 3 whereas a print inside the match will show 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of your branch in match expression is creating new bindings to existing symbols

```
| (len, lastIndex) -> ...
```

so this branch matches with every other case.

If you what to match against existing values in match expression you can use when clase for that:

```
| (a, b) when a = len && b = lastIndex -> ...
```

Another option would be declaring *len* and *lastIndex* as literals to use them in pattern matching but it seems not natural in your case.

```
[<Literal>]
let len = arr.Length
```

Comment: Literal can't be used in this case anyway, you can only use it for, well, literal values, not runtime values like `arr.Length`.